# add fade effect to image swap

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a solution to add a nice fade effect to a few images when I swap them. I'm new to jquery and have seen many solutions but only for a single image instead of multiples ones.Tried the z-index technique but that placed all the images on top of each other.

I'm using this jquery code to swap the images.

```
$(document).ready(function(){



// jQuery image change on hover
$("ul#aside li a img")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "over.png";
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("over", "");
        $(this).attr("src", src);

    });
});
```

Any help or tips is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul#aside li a img")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "over.png";
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.fadeOut("fast", function() {
          $this.attr("src", src).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("over", "");
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.fadeOut("fast", function() {
          $this.attr("src", src).fadeIn("slow");
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: I think it's fadeIn and fadeOut

Comment: That works be it only a bit rough transition. It also looks like the image is swapped, removed, and displayed again. You can see it live here http://nielspilonwebdesign.nl/dev/adri

Comment: @NielsPilon  ... modified my answer using the complete callback on the fade out... give it a try.  It should transition better.

Comment: @JohnHartsock The effect is only once now so that's great. But there's still a white/blank part during the animation. The image swaps between grayscale to fullcolor. Now it's the grayscale, white, color (placeholder image atm) with the effect. If you could remove the white part that would be even more awesome

Comment: i had the blinking problem before myself. its because u are calling the fadein from the callback of fadeout. the way i fixed it was i used two images instead of one. set right on top of each other. then u can fadeout at the same time as fadein. the white blinking will go away.

Comment: @NielsPilon ... Johnny Craig has a great Idea you should give it a shot.

Comment: @JohnnyCraig I'll have a look into your solution. Thanks to all for the help so far :-)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).attr("src", src);
  $(this).fadeIn();
```

`.fadeOut()` will fade an image out